# AndroidTestCase - assertActivityRequiresPermission and assertReadingContentUriRequiresPermission

Tags: android

hoping for some help with the methods assertActivityRequiresPermission and assertReadingContentUriRequiresPermission. It's not behaving the way I thought it will and I'm not seeing where I went wrong.

My understanding is that both activities and providers can be protected by adding android:permission to their respective tags (  and  ) in AndroidManifest.xml. To declare that a client activity has the required permission to start and activity or work with a provider, we declare  under the  tag in what I believe to be at a 'package' level.

So to test how the assert methods in AndroidTestCase works I set up a HelloWorld project and a project to test HelloWorld. This is the manifest for HelloWorld.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.helloandroid"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".HelloAndroidActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".RecipientActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" >
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

I have RecipientActivity protected by RECEIVE_SMS, so I declare using RECEIVE_SMS so that HelloAndroidActivity is able to start RecipientActivity.

Now in my test class,

```
public class TestRecipientActivity extends AndroidTestCase {

    public void testPermissions() {
        String packageName = "com.example.helloandroid";
        String className = packageName + ".RecipientActivity";
        String permission = android.Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS;
        assertActivityRequiresPermission(packageName, className, permission);
    }

    public void testContactsPermissions() {
        final Uri URI = ContactsContract.AUTHORITY_URI;
        final String permission = android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS;
        assertReadingContentUriRequiresPermission(URI, permission);
     }
}
```

Results?

testPermissions() fails with 'AssertionFailError: expected security exception', meaning RecipientActivity is started successfully with no SecurityException thrown.

testContactsPermissions() passed without throwing any exception although I do not have define  anywhere.

Can anyone explain why I'm getting the above results? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You asked this question long time ago and I don't know if you have already solved it.

I am learning Unit-Testing in Android and I had the same problem. At the beginning I thought that the method assertActivityRequiresPermission() tests the permissions declared in < uses-permission >, but then I realized that this method only test if there is a specific permission associated to the activity passed as parameter.

You are associating the same permission to the < uses-permission > and < activity > tags. The point is that the assert works if you delete the permission from < uses-permission >. I think the problem is that this assert is expecting a SecurityException caused because it can't launch the activity without the permission, but you are using that permission in the manifest.xml, so the exception is not thrown.